# Error: Could not find image file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I have `react-native` `ExpoKit` I`OS` app, suddenly I have started to get an error, that app can't find images:

> Could not find image
>   file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/

When I'm creating release build, I can see all images, when I work on simulator or on real device in debug mode, I can't see any images. I have latest version of Xcode, I have correct paths to the images. Any ideas how is possible to fix this problem?